# Removing neck from guitar

Tags: guitar-hero-live

So recently I had to return a faulty guitar and couldn't figure out how your expected to remove the neck since it now is held in with this triangular keyed latch instead of the trigger like one on the old guitars..

How are you supposed to turn this?

I ended up using a hex/allen key but this sheared the latch slightly and would possibly eventually ruin the latch.

I've seen others suggest using a finger pressed into it but I kind of like my fingers and don't want to abuse them.

[image]

Comment: Common trick for irregular screw holes: heat up a soft plastic pen so it becomes melty, and shove it into the screw head. It'll harden, and boom! you got a fancy screwdriver. Used this to unscrew the back of my gameboy color games.
Of course, do this at your own risk etc. etc.

Comment: @schil227 - Would you mind making that an answer? Would prefer to give it more credit than an upvote on a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer)

A common trick to remove irregular screw heads is to heat a soft plastic pen to its melting point and stick it on the screw head. As it cools, it will harden and form to the screwhead, allowing you to unscrew it. I've successfully used this method with a Nintendo 64 and with Gameboy Color cartridges.

Of course, beware chemicals coming from burning plastic, do it in a well ventilated area, wear safety glasses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to be able to take the neck off of the new guitars. I had the same exact issue when a friend came over to play it on release. If you look on the manual or box it is in fine print that it does not detach any more.

Edit:

It appears it will detach though if you can manage to find something to fit that triangle bit well enough. In the video below he uses some kind of old key it looks like.

[Guitar neck removal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc0ODPj7jws)

Comment: But you may be able to take it apart with the trick that schil227 said in the comment on your question.

Comment: I saw that but I'm more concerned with the fact that I may need to return a faulty guitar again at some point which would require me to disassemble it again, the pen trick definitely sounds like it might be a viable option since it doesn't sound like it would cause any damage to the guitar +1 anywho

Comment: @Sayse Please check my edit. Also I understand, as my friend bought the 2 guitar kit and one of the dongles was borderline broken (USB connectors were coming apart)

Comment: I saw that video but that seems like it would do more damage than the hex/allen key did.. I don't think there is a better solution other than schil's prison key or having a friend at activision